# based or located?

Tags: vocabulary

Photo caption: -

"The path of the original Bath Road through town, where so many of the pubs were **based**"

OR

"The path of the original Bath Road through town, where so many of the pubs were **located**"

Which?

Answer (score 3):

Although I am sure that you will find plenty of examples of ‘based’ used as in your first alternative, I think it is better reserved for the location of a place that has other theatres of operation. So the [Oxford Dictionary on line](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/base) defines ‘based’ as:

> **verb 2.** Situate at a specified place as the centre of operations.
>   ‘the Science Policy Review Unit is based at the University of Sussex’
>   ‘a London-based band’

So, I would prefer your second alternative, ‘located’, for a pub that is a single fixed entity.

(Although, taking a cue from the OD, you might consider ‘situated’ instead. That still sounds a little technical — in speech you could get away with just saying ‘were’.)